# How to print label rolls from C# application?

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports, label, barcode

I am trying to develop an application where in my C# application should print product labels when I make a product purchase entry (similar scenario as of a grocery mall).

I would like to make user pre-enter the details of all purchased products.
Data available with me would be Product code and Name; and these should be printed as barcode and text, all in one shot (1000 labels at a time).

**I want to use a Barcode Printer (SATO CG408) to print continuous label rolls.**

So how can I achieve printing task. Previously I used A4 label-sheets to print barcodes and crytal reports to print barcodes, by setting custom label sizes and paper sizes in crystal reports.

But can I use crystal reports for printing continuous labels on barcode printer ?
If yes, how ?

Or any other option to communicate with printer and print the barcodes.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the POS-printers has simple (for implementation too) communication protocol where you can find command to print text, barcode and so on.

Using generated barcodes is a bad idea because the POS-printers prints images slowly.

[You may found protocol for your device here](http://www.satoamerica.com/cms/Operator+and+Technical+Manuals/98.html)

Comment: Oh so that means I should not use crystal reports but directly pass commands to the barcode printer. Meanwhile, I am trying to learn how to directly communicate with printer and use of SGPL (programming language for SATO printers)

Comment: You may try to print generated image as Andrew Cooper said, but you may receive problems with reading barcodes...

Comment: But why do you think so, because as we are using thermal transfer printers, there will be almost no chance of ink spread or blurring of white space. Or do think the image resolution wont be so good

Comment: How about use of Barcode fonts in crystal reports and not an Image?

Comment: We had problems with reading when print image with barcode on POS-printer which doesn'n support barcodes. We had to correct image dimensions and received semitones on it. Barcode fonts doesn't print directly they convert to "image" by driver before send to printer.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs.. I found some support here http://nicholas.piasecki.name/blog/2009/03/sending-raw-epl2-directly-to-a-zebra-lp2844-via-c/

Comment: @Niraj Doshi, interesting but I think you should use `SerialPort` class for communiction if the printer is connected via COM-port. Good luck. :)

Comment: Thanks...printer is connected with USB port

Comment: In this case better raw printing. As you do... :)

Comment: the link in your answer is broken.

Answer (score 1):

The barcode printer should have a Windows Printer Driver which handles the label size.  Crystal Reports, or anything else, should then be able to use it like a normal printer by picking the custom label size.

Comment: One note: design reports on production POS computer, otherwise you may run into driver/OS incompatibilities.